# uint value usage as a parameter in truffle

Tags: truffle

How can I send a uint parameter value to the contract in truffle?

i have a function that has two uint parameter and I wrote test that function but I guess the uint parameters cannt be sent as a correctly. Also I cannot see in mapping too the boolean value result of the uint parameter. (**the HashList is mapping** )

I'm putting log messages in truffle :

```
it('should be mint the token only owner', async()=>{
  const _hash = await actions.generateHash.call(50, '123');
  const inList = await actions.HashList(_hash);
  console.log('is there in list?    '+ inList);
  console.log('hash: '+_hash);
  console.log('all info: '+accounts[3], 50, '123', _hash);

  const res = await actions.create(accounts[3], 50, '123', _hash{from: accounts[0]});

  assert.isTrue(res, 'could not create. Please check contract or test code.' );

  });
```

My test outputs in here :

```
is there in list?false
hash: 38391047091755091013202618179480389830368877342597680687864504738175347992246
all info : 0x916666dBb04c97ea3D92647dF5b0De5Be5cD038B 50 123 BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [
    51521206,       11804147,
    59004577,       116902,
    25125010,       60098687,
    16719740,       18977897,
    526954,         1390628,
    <1 empty item>
  ],
  length: 10,
  red: null
} BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [
    51521206,       11804147,
    59004577,       116902,
    25125010,       60098687,
    16719740,       18977897,
    526954,         1390628,
    <1 empty item>
  ],
  length: 10,
  red: null
}
```

**what is BN in all info output? why the Uint parameters shown as BN ?**

thank you,

Comment: Your code doesn't match your output. How can `_hash` possible yield two different printouts???

Comment: More likely, that long printout is of `res`!

Comment: the _hash result of the generateHash function.

Comment: You have two `console.log` statements for `_hash`, and each one of them results with a different printout. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: @YaseminCırt Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Please forgive goodvibration's gruffness, but it is good they have answered your question.  I will try to clean up most of these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `BN` is a library for calculating with big numbers in JavaScript; see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#bn) for more details
2. In order to print a complex object properly, use `JSON.stringify` on it; for example:

   Instead of `console.log('all info: '+accounts[3], 50, '123', res);`

   Do `console.log('all info: '+accounts[3], 50, '123', JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));`

Comment: @YaseminCırt: 1. Please fix your question according to the comments. It's absolutely impossible for your `_hash` to just "change its value out of thin air". You're also missing a comma in `_hash{from: accounts[0]}`, and I'm guessing that there's a bunch of other basic coding errors. Don't post poorly-phrased questions and expect to get decent answers. 2. If you have a different question, then please post it separately. 3. If this answer has answered your question, then please accept it by clicking on the V next to it. Otherwise, please explain what part has not been answered.